# Using SQL Server 2008 R2 with Visual Studio Express

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

I want to create either "LINQ to SQL" classes or use "Entity Framework" from Visual Studio Express 2010.  When I attempt to add a data source my only options are:

1. "Microsoft Access Database File"
2. "Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5"
3. "Microsoft SQL Server Database File"

Do I need VS2010 Pro to use LINQ to SQL or EF?  I thought I could do all of this from Express.  I even went so far as to install, "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client" and it still doesn't show SQL Server 2008 as a data source.

Thanks!

p.s. I feel like a complete idiot that I cannot get this to work

Comment: Have you tried the `<other>` option?

Comment: The other option?  Please clarrify

Comment: In my copy (granted, it's Premium, not Express), you can choose one of the items in the drop-down, or `<other>`, which shows you all providers on the machine.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "other" choice

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to SQL (L2S) and LINQ to Entities (L2E) (aka Entity Framework) are part of the .NET Framework, and so are part of .NET regardless of what version of VS you use.

Both first appeared in 3.5 and are updated in 4.0, although LINQ to SQL won't be progressed any further in terms of functionality. Hence there isn't a dependency on the IDE. What might be missing is the LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entity designers, but I don't think from memory they are.

If you select Add New Item and look in the Data group you should find "LINQ to SQL classes" and "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" - if not perhaps the designers are not part of Express.

[edit]
Seems this has been asked before:
[Connecting to SQL Server with Visual Studio Express Editions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188963/connecting-to-sql-server-with-visual-studio-express-editions)

Answer (score 0):

For LINQ, use SQLMetal to generate the spew and then just form connection string and let the code connect - you shoudldn't let VS mess with your data representation anyway. SQLMetal's spew is very clean and you can also edit it, once you learn what's what, to make it lighter - or heavier :-) - there are hooks for more code as well.

Before that check that your SQL instance is running and visible - VS installed SQL Express as default instance it can prevent real SQL's default instance from even being visible - a lot of uninstalls in your future if that happened.