# Visual Studio Express can't change data source

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, connection-string

I am trying to add a SQL Server data source to a C# console app.

When I try and add a new connection to my .dbml file the only Data Source available is Microsoft SQL Server Database File (sqlclient) whereas I need Microsoft SQL Server (sqlclient).

The change button is grayed out, so I can't change it.

[image]

How do I change this?

(I wondered if it was a bug, so tried uninstalling/reinstalling Visual Studio - but still no joy.)

Comment: Not a bug, it's a limitation on Express Version of the IDE. Mitchel Sellers answered there and he also gives the workaround. (Changing the connection string manually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a limitation of the Express product and you can get around it with a modification of your SQL Server connection string manually.  For more information have a look at this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188963/connecting-to-sql-server-with-visual-studio-express-editions).

Comment: Could you add the relevant workaround to this question? The other one was closed and will eventually be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by using the workaround from the post above:

> Workaround:
>
> 1.Open your solution in Visual Web Developer Express. It will not load some of the projects in the solution but it is ok.
>
> 2.Make a new connection in Database Explorer to the required database from SQL Server.
>
> 3.Add a new class library project.
>
> 4.Add a LINQ to SQL Classes item and link it to your database.
>
> 5.Close the solution.
>
> 6.Open the solution in Visual C# Express.
>
> Now you have a LINQ to SQL classes library that is linked to your SQL
>   Server database in Visual C# Express.