# How to add more datasources on visual c#

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using visual c# 2010 and I want to be able to add an ms sql database as datasource. But all I can see from the choices is for database files. Is this really all that's built into to an express edition, or can I download something that will allow me to add more data sources.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed due to using the express edition.  But You can circumvent it by changing the connection string manually - as in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/189058/275076)

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the Express Edition you can't do that.