# Visual Studio 2010 Database Browser won't connect to SQL Server consistantly

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I've looked at the other sort of similar questions here and none seem to have a usable answer for me. I am perplexed at the error message I am getting - its a database - it's supposed to allow multiple processes to access it. What else is the point of having a database?!?

OK. Find my zen like calm again...

```
Environment:
  Visual Studio 2010 Express (C# in this particular case)
  SQL Server 2012 R0 set up for windows authentication
  i7 based PC, 8 cores, 16GB RAM, Windows 7 Pro x64
```

I have a database I created with a few simple tables. I know where the MDF file is. I can access it via SQL Server Management Studio just fine.

Here is what Microsoft says to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171890.aspx

Step 9 is where it fails with the error that the file is in use. That's it. No way past this point. Why isn't there a way to indicate the SQL Server - why do I have to go to the file? Is the file supposed to be totally disconnected from the running SQL Server process? How does that make sense? That is just insane - how are other processes supposed to be able to reach it? Isn't that the point of having a database? The Dude does not abide!

Theory - this is how Microsoft wants to get me to upgrade from Express to something I pay for. [insert mandatory gray beard grumble about Microsoft]. I notice that in Visual Studio for pay the 
Database Browser is replaced with the Server Browser... I smell a fish.

```
Before you answer:
  Yes. I turned it off then on again.
  Yes. I uninstalled then reinstalled the database.
  Yes. I did that other thing you suggest to users you normally don't trust to flip
    on a light switch correctly.
  Yes. This facility was cleared out of voodoo, gremlins and black cats ages ago.
    There is plenty of natural sunlight so the bastards aren't coming back.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It is not hard but the solution is hidden in a tricky place! You have to open up Visual Web Developer, open your solution there, and add a LINQ to SQL class. Web Developer has access to SQL Server. Once set up it should be easy to use.

For more details see it here!

[Connecting to SQL Server with Visual Studio Express Editions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188963/connecting-to-sql-server-with-visual-studio-express-editions/4708791#comment11322058_4708791)