# Connecting to SQL Server with Visual C# express

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I'm using this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188963/connecting-to-sql-server-with-visual-studio-express-editions)[image: pic] but it's still not clear to me. I'm stuck with steps 3 & 4. Can anyone post a printscreen doing these steps? Sorry if it's asking too much but I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Basically, you need to do your Entity Framework or Linq2SQL work in VWD, and your Windows Forms development in VC - i.e. you need both Express apps installed. You may need to compile your Data layer in VWD and then add an assembly reference to it from VC.

Answer (score 3):

Step 3: from the menu, pick `File > New > Project` and then in the dialog, pick `Class Library`:

[image]

Step 4: in that class library project, in the Solution Explorer, right-click and choose `Add > New Item` and then from the menu, pick the `Linq-to-SQL classes`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! How do I link the LINQ to SQL Classes to my database?

Comment: @Afungus: once you've added the Linq-to-SQL classes, you'll have to pick a database to get your tables and other database objects from

Comment: @Afungus: see [Scott Guthrie's excellent Using Linq-to-SQL series](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) of blog posts illustrating everything you ever wanted to know about Linq-to-SQL (and more!)

Comment: I tried [connecting](http://i.imgur.com/SfjVp.png) the database to the LINQ to SQL Classes but when I open my Visual C# Express, the database still doesn't show in the [database explorer](http://i.imgur.com/h98Y3.png).